# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection. This is the error that pops up when I try to run this code

Tags: r

```
tripdata_2020_05 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202005-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_06 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202006-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_07 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202007-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_08 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202008-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_09 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202009-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_10 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202010-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_11 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202011-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2020_12 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2021_01 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202101-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2021_02 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202102-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2021_03 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202103-divvy-tripdata.csv")
tripdata_2021_04 <- read.csv("../input/Excel/202104-divvy-tripdata.csv")
```

## I'm trying to load the data set and when I run it this pops up

Warning in file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '../input/Excel/202006-divvy-tripdata.csv': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Comment: .... does the file exist?

Comment: (in particular, check that your working directory is what you think it is, so the `../` is being evaluated relative to the intended place).

Comment: Try `file.exists("../input/Excel/202005-divvy-tripdata.csv")`.